# Opening web page from winform app opens too many tabs?

Tags: c#, winforms

I have some code that uses a custom popupNotifier that subscribes to a click event like so:

`popupNotifier1.Click += new EventHandler(PopUpClicked);`

That means when someone clicks open the popup it launches a url string.  Assume `_url` is global for the time being.

I do this in PopUpClicked:

```
  public void PopUpClicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            System.Diagnostics.Process proc = new System.Diagnostics.Process();
            System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo(_url);
            proc.StartInfo = startInfo;
            proc.Start();
        }
```

The url, `_url` contains a string like:

`http://mysite/mypage.aspx?MyID=100`

This works all fine..it opens the page but I noticed it will open up multiple tabs of the same page.
I cant understand why?

## edit

Just to add more code I call this from a timer event that hits every minute, but notice the if condition, it only subscribes to the event if there is data:

```
 private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            SqlDataReader sr;
            string ticketInfo = String.Empty;
            string url = String.Empty;
            bool hasData = false;
            using (SqlConnection sc = new SqlConnection(_connString))
            {
                using (SqlCommand scmd = new SqlCommand("select_poll"))
                {
                    scmd.Connection = sc;
                    scmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                    scmd.Parameters.Add("LoginID", SqlDbType.BigInt).Value = _userLoginID;
                    scmd.Parameters.Add("FacilityID", SqlDbType.BigInt).Value = _userFacilityID;
                    sc.Open();
                    sr = scmd.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.CloseConnection);

                    if (sr != null)
                    {
                        while (sr.Read())
                        {
                            hasData = true;
                            ticketInfo += sr["TicketID"].ToString() + " - " + sr["Ticket"].ToString() + Environment.NewLine;
                            _url = "http://mysite/mypage.aspx?ID=" + sr["TicketID"].ToString();
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

            if (hasData)
            {
                popupNotifier1.TitleColor = System.Drawing.Color.Green;
                popupNotifier1.ContentText = ticketInfo;
                popupNotifier1.Scroll = true;
                popupNotifier1.TitlePadding = new System.Windows.Forms.Padding(2);
                popupNotifier1.ContentPadding = new System.Windows.Forms.Padding(2);
                popupNotifier1.Image = Properties.Resources.medical;
                popupNotifier1.ImagePadding = new System.Windows.Forms.Padding(10);
                popupNotifier1.Click += new EventHandler(PopUpClicked);
                popupNotifier1.Popup();
            }
        }

        public void PopUpClicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            System.Diagnostics.Process proc = new System.Diagnostics.Process();
            System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo(_url);
            proc.StartInfo = startInfo;
            proc.Start();
        }
```

Comment: It's because you're attaching the event handler multiple times.  You haven't shown us how you do it, so we couldn't tell you what mistake you made in doing so.

Comment: or do u have multiple subscription to same event?

Comment: No @AppDeveloper it is called from a timer that hits once a minute but let me post more code to relay the message.

Comment: @Servy see my edit with full code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're subscribing to the event multiple times.  In this particular case, you're subscribing to the event any time a particular condition is met when your timer fires.  It would appear that this happens more than once.

You almost certainly want to attach the event handler outside of the tick event, probably when the form is first loaded.

Comment: I cant do that because the ticking is responsible for being done right when the app starts as it is polling the database.

Comment: @oJM86o I fail to see how any of that means that you can't attach the event handler when the form is first loaded, or even when the popup is first created.

Comment: the code pulls data from a database and generates the `_url` which is needed at the time of the timer tick event.  Once I have some data (any data) `hasData` is set to true which means I got a valid record.  I then enter the `if (hasData)` condition allowing me to subscribe to the click event of the popup.  Otherwise how else can I subscribe to it, remember the `_url` changes for each record.

Comment: @oJM86o `_url` isn't a parameter to that method, and it's not like it's a closed over value.  It's just an instance field.  You're attaching the **exact same method** every single time.  You can attach that method when the form is first loaded knowing that the `_url` field will be populated with a value at a later time, before the popup is actually popped up.

Answer (score 0):

```
popupNotifier1.Click += new EventHandler(PopUpClicked);
```

the above lines subscribes to the `event` multiple times, so when first time, when `PopUp` is fires, it opens `one tab`, next time `2 tab`, then next time `three tab` n so on

add handler only once, the best way will be, just before u enable the timer in your code

Like

```
popupNotifier1.Click += new EventHandler(PopUpClicked);
timer1.Enabled = true;
```

#### Fixed Code

```
private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            SqlDataReader sr;
            string ticketInfo = String.Empty;
            string url = String.Empty;
            bool hasData = false;
            using (SqlConnection sc = new SqlConnection(_connString))
            {
                using (SqlCommand scmd = new SqlCommand("select_poll"))
                {
                    scmd.Connection = sc;
                    scmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                    scmd.Parameters.Add("LoginID", SqlDbType.BigInt).Value = _userLoginID;
                    scmd.Parameters.Add("FacilityID", SqlDbType.BigInt).Value = _userFacilityID;
                    sc.Open();
                    sr = scmd.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.CloseConnection);

                    if (sr != null)
                    {
                        while (sr.Read())
                        {
                            hasData = true;
                            ticketInfo += sr["TicketID"].ToString() + " - " + sr["Ticket"].ToString() + Environment.NewLine;
                            _url = "http://mysite/mypage.aspx?ID=" + sr["TicketID"].ToString();
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

            if (hasData)
            {
                popupNotifier1.TitleColor = System.Drawing.Color.Green;
                popupNotifier1.ContentText = ticketInfo;
                popupNotifier1.Scroll = true;
                popupNotifier1.TitlePadding = new System.Windows.Forms.Padding(2);
                popupNotifier1.ContentPadding = new System.Windows.Forms.Padding(2);
                popupNotifier1.Image = Properties.Resources.medical;
                popupNotifier1.ImagePadding = new System.Windows.Forms.Padding(10);
                popupNotifier1.Popup();
            }
        }

        public void PopUpClicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            System.Diagnostics.Process proc = new System.Diagnostics.Process();
            System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo(_url);
            proc.StartInfo = startInfo;
            proc.Start();
        }
```

Comment: I dont understand how this would help me???  The timer cannot be enabled there, it is enabled in my form load event...and I need it to be like that.

Comment: @oJM86o - try the above code, there is just one line changed!

Comment: where are you subscribing to the popupclicked routine?  I do not see that in the code...

Comment: Why bother copying that entire code snippet just to show that one line of code is deleted.  Just ay that you deleted/moved it and it will be much clearer.